# Looking for errors in my proof that the normal vector to a path is zero.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

Let $\mathbf c : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be a smooth ($C^\infty$) path where $\mathbf c(t) = \left(c_1(t), c_2(t), \ldots, c_n(t) \right)$.  Let $\mathbf T(t)$ be defined as the normalized tangent vector to $\mathbf c(t)$, $\frac{\mathbf c'(t)}{\Vert \mathbf c'(t) \Vert}.$

A homework problem (which I already turned in) asked for the value of $\mathbf T'(t)$, the non-normalized normal vector.  I calculated it using the quotient rule as follows:
\begin{align}
\mathbf T'(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\mathbf c'(t)}{\Vert \mathbf c'(t) \Vert}\right) &= \frac{\mathbf c''(t)\Vert\mathbf c'(t)\Vert - \mathbf c'(t)\frac{\mathbf c'(t) \cdot \mathbf c''(t)}{\Vert\mathbf c'(t)\Vert}}{\Vert\mathbf c'(t)\Vert^2} \\ &= \frac{\mathbf c''(t)\Vert\mathbf c'(t)\Vert - \mathbf c'(t)\frac{\mathbf c'(t) \cdot \mathbf c''(t)}{\Vert\mathbf c'(t)\Vert}}{\Vert\mathbf c'(t)\Vert^2} \cdot \frac{\Vert \mathbf c'(t) \Vert}{\Vert \mathbf c'(t) \Vert} \\ &= \frac{\mathbf c''(t)\left[\mathbf c'(t)\cdot\mathbf c'(t)\right] - \mathbf c''(t)\left[\mathbf c'(t)\cdot\mathbf c'(t)\right]}{\Vert \mathbf c'(t) \Vert^3} \\ &= 0,
\end{align}
where the derivative of the norm of $\mathbf c'(t)$ was calculated as follows:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\Vert\mathbf c'(t)\Vert &= \frac{2c'_1(t)c_1''(t) + 2c'_2(t)c_2''(t) + \cdots + 2c_n'(t)c_n''(t)}{2\sqrt{c_1'(t)^2 + c_2'(t)^2 + \cdots + c_n'(t)^2}} \\
&= \frac{\mathbf c'(t) \cdot \mathbf c''(t)}{\Vert\mathbf c'(t)\Vert}.
\end{align}

I'm virtually positive the answer is not zero, but I can't find anything wrong with what I wrote.  Can you please point out any mistakes I made (or, if this is correct, tell me so)?  Thanks!

Comment: $c'(t)(c'(t)\cdot c''(t))\neq c''(t)(c'(t)\cdot c'(t))$

Comment: But isn't the dot product commutative?

Comment: yes.But the operation between $c'(t)$ and $(c'(t)\cdot c''(t))$ is not dot product since $(c'(t)\cdot c''(t))$ is a real number, not a vector.

Comment: Oh.  I first thought that dotting the first two vectors and multiplying the resulting scalar by the third vector yielded the same thing as dotting the second two and multiplying the result by the first, but after a bit of thinking I realized that was wrong.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: you're welcome!